# Get base name of file without file extension

Tags: string, batch-file

Let's say I'd have a file named `"testfile.txt"` set on a variable:`%File%` and I'd like to remove the extension when echoing it .  `Echo %File:~0,8%`   would come out as `"testfile"` but what I want to do is to have it display anything and everything to the left of the `".txt"` because I won't always make files which have 8 characters in their name.

Is there a simple solution to this ?

Comment: [**Here**](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) is a good site that goes over different ways to edit `%%~I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

```js
for %%I in ("testfile.txt") do echo %%~nI
```

or

```js
for %%I in ("%file%") do echo %%~nI
```

Do `help for` in a cmd console window and see the last two pages for more information on tilde operations.

---

There is another way to accomplish what you want, using substring substitution similar to your attempts illustrated in your question.

```js
set "file=testfile.txt"
echo %file:.=&rem;%
```

That substitutes the dot with `&rem;`.  When the variable is evaluated, the batch interpreter treats the newly substituted data as a compound command.  And since everything following `rem` is treated as a remark to be ignored, you're left with only `testfile` as the output.  This will only work if:

- you don't include quotation marks in your variable value
- your filename only includes the one dot
- you don't do it within a parenthetical code block (`if` statement or `for` loop) where delayed expansion is required

Comment: if you would happen to know where i could learn more about the method you used with "%file:.=&rem;%" i'd be extremely grateful

Comment: That's basically just `%haystack:needle=replace%`. That method will allow using a `*` wildcard at the *beginning* of `needle`, but not the end. http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php has some other cmd string manipulation methods you might find useful. You know, if in your situation your file will always have a `.txt` extension, you can simplify matters a bit by replacing `.txt` with nothing -- `echo %file:.txt=%`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
set "file=testfile.txt"
call :removeExtension "%file%"
echo %newFile%
pause
goto :eof

:removeExtension
set "newFile=%~n1"
goto :eof
```

However, this only works if the file has no path. If it does, you can do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=files\testfile.txt"
call :removeExtension "%file%"
echo %newFile%
pause
goto :eof

:removeExtension
set "file=%~1"
set "newFile=!file:%~x1=!"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Seems like it would have been easier to just use the FOR command.

Comment: @Squashman yes, but I feel like this is easier to understand, and he specifically asked for a simple solution